# What is the answer to the third squirrel question?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm stuck on the 3rd question asking how many candies does the candiest person in the world possess?

Comment: Yeah I am stuck on this one right now too.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-is-asked-which-is-a-collection-of-other-asked-que

Answer (score 9):

Type in the number of candies you have at the moment. ;)

Comment: @3ventic - Actually, it DOES provide an answer. It IS the answer.

Comment: @5pike wow. Maybe I shouldn't review these

Comment: And that’s supposed to be an answer that someone could come up with on their own‽‽‽ There is nothing obvious or logical about that. I tried answers like `infinite`, `all of them`, `0`, and `1` because those all make sense. There is nothing sensible about the player themselves being the candiest person since it has already been established that the player most definitely is *not* the candiest yet (maybe when the candy box is finally opened, sure, but not at the point where the squirrel comes in). This is exactly the sort of reason why cheats are necessary and don’t count as “cheating”. ◔_◔

Comment: (Plus, it’s hard to enter the exact number once it starts going up a few dozen per second.)

Answer (score 0):

It is the number of candies you have at the moment, but if that's changing too quickly to enter, go to the lollipop farm and develop it to the point where you can have alligators.  Get enough alligators to consume candy faster than you gain it, then eat all your candy.  It'll stay at 0 and then you can put that as your answer.

(Note, you can turn off feeding the alligators to build up candy stores again.)